# Command line arguments in C - Passing 12, machine reading 49

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have this piece of code in C:

```
int x = 52706108;

 if(argc >= 2){
  int val = *argv[1];
  int xor = x^val;
  printf("The xor value between %d and %d is %d in decimal\n",x,val,xor);
 }
```

I'm compiling it like this:

```
gcc -m32 -g -o a5_1 a5_1.c
```

Running it like this:

```
./a5_1 12
```

And this is my output:

```
The xor value between 52706108 and 49 is 52706061 in decimal
```

I can't understand why I'm passing the parameter "12" but the machine is reading 49 instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That `49` is the ASCII code point of the `1` in your *string* argument `12`. That's because `argv` is an array of `char` *pointers,* each of which points to a C string containing the argument. So, it's as if you've defined `argv[1]` to be `{'1', '2', '\0')`.

If you want to convert the argument to an *integer,* use something like:

```
int num = atoi (argv[1]);
```

or, preferably with error checking and to avoid undefined behaviour in the event the number is out of range:

```
char *nextChar;
long num = strtol (argv[1], &nextChar, 10);
if ((nextChar == argv[1]) || (*nextChar != '\0')) {
    // Is either empty or has invalid characters.
    return -1;
}

// String was non-empty and all-numeric.
```

---

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long x = 52706108;
    if (argc >= 2) {
        char *nextChar;
        long val = strtol (argv[1], &nextChar, 10);
        if ((nextChar == argv[1]) || (*nextChar != '\0')) {
            printf ("Invalid input '%s'\n", argv[1]);
            return -1;
        }
        long xor = x^val;
        printf("Xor between %ld and %ld is %ld in decimal\n",x,val,xor);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of that program (when given `12` as an argument) is:

```
Xor between 52706108 and 12 is 52706096 in decimal
```

Comment: @PatricioJerí, expansion achieved :-)

Comment: Elements of ARGV are character pointers, not integers. You need to convert the string to an integer, before using it as an integer.

Comment: You're right sir, I was missing atoi() for that, thank you :P

Comment: I would add that be careful about XORing signed integer values. If you are using only number which are unsigned, then use the relevant types. Otherwise, MS bit could alter your results.

Comment: `atoi` should never be used with user input. Even if you're not going to do any explicit error checking `strtol` is still "safer".

Comment: Yes, hence "something like". But I'll add `strtol` to the answer as well.

Comment: @CharlesBailey `atoi` is not unsafe in the way `gets` or `sprintf` is. If you don't do error checking, `strtol` is equivalent to `atoi` and there is no reason to avoid the latter.

Comment: @user4815162342: It's just as unsafe. If you pass it something that is out of range it causes _undefined behavior_. Unless the input is controlled it should never be used. Even then why not use `strtol`?

Comment: @CharlesBailey It does cause undefined behavior, but claiming that it's "just as unsafe" as `gets` is hyperbole—signed integer overflow is also undefined behavior, but no one would reasonably claim that it is just as unsafe as a function that has no choice but to overrun your buffer on invalid input. A non-pathological implementation of `atoi` will return garbage on error, and a reasonable modern implementation will define it as `strtol (nptr, NULL, 10)`, like glibc does. While it should be avoided in production code, it is quite acceptable for beginners.

Comment: I am totally agree with @CharlesBailey, before using atoi you must check char* data.